# Hexadecimal to Binary

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion

Convert a hexadecimal number (of any size) into a binary number.

**Input**
A *POSITIVE* hexadecimal number with a `0x` in the beginning. A valid input will always match the following regex: `0x[0-9a-fA-F]+`. If the input is *not* a valid hexadecimal number, that is, anything not matching this regex, the output should be `0`.

**Output**
The hexadecimal converted to binary.

**Winning**
Original Code-Golf Rules, Lowest amount of bites `(bytes)`.

**Examples**

```
IN: 0x12
OUT: 10010

IN: 0xFF
OUT: 11111111

IN: 0XFF
OUT: 0

IN: #0ac4
OUT: 0

IN: 0x00101011
OUT: 100000001000000010001

IN: 0x525600
OUT: 10100100101011000000000

IN: 0x58f70555118ec400
OUT: 101100011110111000001010101010100010001100011101100010000000000

IN: 0x6669795966AF3000
OUT: 110011001101001011110010101100101100110101011110011000000000000

IN: 0b018474
OUT: 0

IN: 9577383
OUT: 0

IN: -483355
OUT: 0

IN: -0xf9ad92
OUT: 0

IN: 0xG
OUT: 0

IN: 0x0xa
OUT: 0
```

Comment: When you say "If the input isn't a valid hexadecimal number", what types of things can it be? A number in a different base? A non-numeric object? Some object made to crash the program is evaluated, possibly in a non-catchable way? Really, I would have suggested avoiding input validation at all; it feels like a [chameleon challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/20260).

Comment: @xnor, you're right. It does seem a bit focused on the input checking. But a valid hexadecimal number is pretty self-explanatory. Look at the examples, I think those explain it better than I can.

Comment: @HashimKayani: The problem's not to do with what *valid* input can arrive, but what *invalid* input can arrive. Suppose someone's writing a function submission. Can the input be, say, a hashtable rather than a string? (That said, is a hexadecimal number even a string in the first place?) Or suppose someone's writing a full program submission, attempts to take input, and gets a disk I/O error. Is that considered something that isn't a hexadecimal number (leading to an output of 0), or can the program just crash in that case?

Comment: [Inferring rules from test cases](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8078/20260) is not OK and likely will get the challenge closed as unclear. Besides that, the examples aren't clear to me. "#0ac4" makes it seem like any extra character(s) can be included.

Comment: Okay, I'll make the rules a bit more clear. I apologize for that. It does seem a bit vague.

Comment: I'm still not clear after the edit what inputs are possible. Is `#0ac4` still a valid test case?

Comment: Your second testcase doesn't match your regex (the `X` is uppercase).

Comment: Do we need to take care of leading zeroes? Can we output something like `00011010`

Comment: Can You add a test case with the correct prefix but invalid data please (`0xG` e.g.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth, 15 bytes

```
.B&qr0<z2"0x"vz
```

Explanation:

```
             vz  Evaluate the input as a literal, to get a number (casts to integer for hexadecimal input)
      <z2        Select the first two characters of (string) input
    r0           cast to lowercase (0X -> 0x)
   q     "0x"    check whether the text starts with "0x" or "0X" (negative numbers don't) 
  &              If it does, return the casted number
.B               and convert to binary string
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.B%26qr0<z2"0x"vz&input=0101&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0x12%0A0XFF%0A11111111%0A%230ac4%0A0x00101011%0A0x525600%0A0x58f70555118ec400%0A0x6669795966AF3000%0A0b018474%0A9577383%0A-483355%0A-0xf9ad92&debug=0)

With a rules clarification (that `0x` must be lowercase) in the OP, you can remove `r0` for 13 bytes.

```
.B&q<z2"0x"vz
```

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <s>67</s> <s>62</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```py
n=input()
try:print bin(int(n,n[1]<'x'))[2:]
except:print 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59nm5lXUFqioclVUlRpVVCUmVeikJSZpwGkNfJ08qINY23UK9Q1NaONrGK5UiuSUwtKoKoM/v9XN6hISU1MSUpNTVMHAA)

Version that errors on invalid input (27 bytes):

```py
lambda n:bin(int(n,16))[2:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ5WUmaeRmVeikadjaKapGW1kFfu/oAgooJCmoW5QkZKamJKUmpqmrvkfAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
Î2£„0xQi¹Hb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@4z@jQ4kcN8wwqAjMP7fRI@v/foMLMzMzS3NLU0szM0c3YwMAAAA)

**Explanation**

```
Î             # initialize stack with 0 and push input
 2£           # get the first 2 chars of input
   „0xQ       # compare to "0x"
       i      # if equal
        ¹H    # convert input from base-16 to base-10
          b   # convert to binary
```

Comment: Doesn't work with the test case `0XFF`.

Comment: @Okx: Both the regex and the input section of the question states that correct input starts with `0x` so I'd say that specific test-case is wrong.

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't notice that.

Comment: [9 bytes by using the new `Å?`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fI6n4UcM8g4rDrfZa//8bVJiZmVmaW5pampk5uhkbGBgAAA) or [10 bytes by still using the legacy](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fI6nY6NDiRw3zDCoCtf7/N6gwMzOzNLc0tTQzc3QzNjAwAAA).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>66 65</s> 63 bytes

```php
<?=decbin(hexdec(preg_filter("#^0x([a-f\d]+$)#i","$1",$argn)));
```

run as pipe with `-F`.

Without the `0x`, the worst problem would be that both `hexdec` and `base_convert` simply ignore characters that are not hex; but with it, there has to be an explicit validity check anyway.

---

45 bytes without the `0x`:

```php
<?=decbin(ctype_xdigit($argn)*hexdec($argn));
```

Comment: `echo stristr($a=$argn,"0X")==$a?decbin(hexdec(ltrim($a,Xx0))):0;` Is this a nice Alternative? It should working for the given testcases

Comment: @JörgHülsermann: It´s a nice alternative, and it´s working for all _given_ test cases, but it does _not_ check the hex value for validity (see my comment on `hexdec` and `base_convert`).

Comment: I know and I think the question is a joke with the given testcases.

Comment: `echo decbin(hexdec(preg_filter("#^0x([a-f\d]+$)#i","$1",$argn)));`

Comment: -2 Bytes `<?=` istead of `echo ` with -F option

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 402 bytes

```
@echo off
set/ps=
set r=0
if not %s:~0,2%==0x goto g
if %s%==0x goto g
if %s:0=%==x goto g
set t=%s%
for %%h in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f)do call set t=%%t:%%h=%%
if not %t%==x goto g
set s=%s:~2%
for %%h in (0.0000 1.0001 2.0010 3.0011 4.0100 5.0101 6.0110 7.0111 8.1000 9.1001 a.1010 b.1011 c.1100 d.1101 e.1110 f.1111)do call set s=%%s:%%~nh=%%~xh%%
set r=%s:.=%
:g
echo %r:*1=1%
```

Takes input on STDIN. 8 lines are then mostly wasted on input validation, so the interesting lines are line 11, which replaces each hex digit with its binary equivalent, but due to Batch limitations, with a leading `.`, line 12, which deletes all the `.`s, and line 14, which removes leading 0s. However this fails for inputs like `0x0` so I "invalidate" those which means 0 is output instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 35 bytes

```
{(m/^0x(.+)/&&:16(~$0)//0).base(2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>53</s> <s>52</s> <s>49</s> <s>50</s> <s>52</s> 45 bytes

(Non-competing as it doesn't handle inputs of *any* size; I just got lucky with the sample inputs)

```js
f=

h=>+/^0x[\da-f]+$/i.test(h)&&(+h).toString(2)

console.log(f`0x12`);
console.log(f`0XFF`);
console.log(f`#0ac4`);
console.log(f`0x00101011`);
console.log(f`0x525600`);
console.log(f`0x58f70555118ec400`);
console.log(f`0x6669795966AF3000`);
console.log(f`0b018474`);
console.log(f`9577383`);
console.log(f`-483355`);
console.log(f`-0xf9ad92`);
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>116</s> <s>111</s> 110 bytes

```js
f=
s=>/^0x[\da-f]+$/i.test(s)?s.replace(/./g,c=>parseInt(4+c,36).toString(2).slice(4)).replace(/0+10*(.)/,'$1'):0
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>0
```

Not limited to 53 bits of precision. Edit: Saved 5 bytes by rewriting my digit conversion, which also reduces my language requirements to ES6. Saved 1 byte thanks to @l4m2.

Comment: You can reduce the length by 13 bytes by evaluating each character as the hex value. [Try it Online](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#LY3JCoMwFEX3fkboIg@vSWrtCFraX@iyA0iMIqRGTBb@vQ3F3YE7nLZcfFnJj5qfr6bO2ne6kb0Ixgfu6eqFt702PCcxmdHWEaWQHXRZcaaUYilPI8ws1UQiuEeY@qGLdVqHWUF0UVHBFLbIsUOBPQ444oQzbrhDo4FBy4QfbR84AyPxrUceFetxot3gnTXCuo77f9gSJcsP)

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk That doesn't solve the question as posed.

Comment: Here, I removed leading zeroes from from the first conversion [Try it Online](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#LY3LCsIwEEX3fsbgYobepvGthVb0F1z6gJImJRDbYrLw77WIuwuHc66rPrGqi4d@X29tk7t7Ni@8SjYmjnKMKgZvLC9FvewYmmkWqujABl6qmtkfSWtNJZFknDHpN2VGRKXhkl6@7yZT/o18LVLq6Y00FlhihTU22GKHPQ444QyDFhaOVByDT0wgUc9mZFPV//DMDH0cglVh6Dj@oBOZfb4) still 2 bytes shorter.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk I combined it with Arnauld's answer and got it down to 103: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#Hc3bCoJAFEbh@x5jENwb/8ax7Aga9QpddpRxlIEppfFCsJ69pOvFx6qyr89yiq@qp9O5LKbVJeIgttL0RpPn9zu8qZBPyUW@TOsKbSiWcQ0qYXmE0V31wWB3yTYMP8FQfu4su@bYveyzphlL7@xIpinz@BEKCWaYI8UCS6ywxgZ7HKBRwqAS0rfOdiQgWD6KlnSWC9WLSPNEN0/fOCNdU5P/x4p58v0B "JavaScript (Node.js) – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk Wait, that doesn't work for the fifth test case `0x00101011`, sorry.

Comment: Can you `.slice(4)` rather than `.slice(-4)`?

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>109 108</s> 107 bytes

*-1 thanks to l4m2*

Works for any input size.

```javascript
s=>/1.*|0$/.exec((/^0x([\da-f]+)$/i.exec(s)||'_0')[1].replace(/./g,d=>(`0x1`+d-0).toString(2).slice(1)))[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJfb4IwFMXf9ylMZkI7R3uvUP5s0WQvvu5hW7LEucmgEBYiRszCg9@dIVZAULPbBEh7zvndlv54v17mb@L1Vl@lgSzCSZFNphzZ3Q6GnMlc@oTwT8jJ/CPw9HAxokMeH@YzuttpX6DROS7YRq4Tz5eEMx7dB5MpWUKOy1GgA2Xb9GW7iVcRGVOWJXGpQkrpHBaFn66yNJEsSSMSEq20jDVKHwenxfng@e31YYAACDddz/tsds2jqmu7Bc83@76jrY/J9/By4Imp1VpV7Tf2M8RYWAAdbJNRbVBh4FhnUpzQBiEEoiN9U@W1Uip4WfuH6qYZqjelUR9whWZZlmu7wrWsp5kBXRoeslA1X2HrHWCzVi@1WGdo34COaZsXTqind4VtG47R/Y8X9brpGIYQ/9dDHrpe4HZuZa0v/gA)

Comment: Hmm ... 2 experienced golfers submitting JS solutions more than twice as long as [mine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116218/58974) has me wondering if I've missed something in the challenge.

Comment: @Shaggy It all depends on the interpretation of the first line of the challenge. I took it for granted that _'of any size'_ was a definite requirement -- and so did Neil apparently.

Comment: @Shaggy Just to clarify for everyone: your approach works for up to `0x1fffffffffffff` -- aka `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` -- and returns rounded results beyond that. By luck, the two large test cases are rounded correctly.

Comment: Huh, I didn't realise that @Shaggy's code worked by accident; I guess I should have counted the distance between the first and last `1` bits in the result. By the way, do you need the `$` in the first regexp?

Comment: @Neil I don't think I can get rid of this `$`. The idea is to get the final zero if there's no `1` at all in the result.

Comment: Yes, I was just forgetting how regexps matched alternations.

Comment: ``+`0x1${d}` `` => `'0x1'+d-0`

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 45 bytes

```
arg '0X' n
if n>'' then say x2b(n)
else say 0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 149 bytes

```
.
;$&
T`L`l
f
71
e
70
d
61
c
60
b
51
a
50
9
41
8
40
7
31
6
30
5
21
4
20
3
11
2
10
;(\d{4})
$1
;(\d{3})
0$1
;(\d\d)
00$1
;
000
^(?!0{7}x).*
0
0{7}x0*
```

(note the trailing newline)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#Lc27asNAEIXh/n@LECfIBpuZ3Z294CKkUZqUKVKYIFmyKj@AwPjZlbUSppjvHBjmpfnolgPHzStf3Wd3ZSIpF5IwEpWBKJwxpceEQlAyQUh4JeIFwykBJ3hUcahwbE7jLdy3bPTPvlr@w2msXkNdwk/z9iS3dJ@3hx3CStmxLDKrQ77blmfph4DMIvoYrTRnsR5X5CmJmanmyxDWKsZYUrES43vrHy/kLJpDChRLyWfPPmTvzdjLPJV@LO4X)

Here is an alternate solution at the cost of 7 bytes: [Try it!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LY25agNBEETz@gtj2awEEt0z03OwgXGyThw6MOhgj9FG/oABjb593VqbDt6rgqJfmo9@OaDdvOKr/@x/MNcrgqZcJ3jlWAeIMtUIpwzVwyqlOhilrQasPM55TEHsGYzjhUt7BqFtTvnm7lts@M@tOv2HU1Zfg4Jwad6e6BbuZXvY6XRV2mFZqLABfXcdnmmYHKgQ8eNYVYx4HavEOZCIMMfr5NbKe59CkuT9e2cfL2gkji44JAnBRou9i9aKYE9lTkNO5hc)

Comment: [Slightly golfed](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#HcuxTgNBDIThft4CEVAISjTeXdu7FaI5GkoKJAS6yyVX8QArIZ798CE3n36N7/Yv43oCyd093sbX8Rtc4AJe4QQvsPAMC5@h4QkabijhihJ25LAhhxUpXJDCGRJOEOJr/3TDH//tH5TPx93D6YAYbIEHrCu7JPB9GHDLaS5gJ2W7@O@a1MgNdXGqqki9zuU/mVnzps3secjc0plSixc0dc8141hqzqo4si9turT0Bw). [Alternative approach](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#Lc29jsIwEATgft8CHaAAChr/rNeuEE2uuZICKQeyE5KKB7CEePYQR2il0czX7Kb6jdMl/sUnHQnAeluyan1I9XjbkZpJURFbS/@lIlWrjZPUDQvNcomGJXT/jzGWoa3zqR8i6F6dVnjJO7dQt8N6d9wTaAHsaZqQlSZcm4Z@kHpLyIAqNz/JrNkBpfhRwMxK@aG3CznnggQOzp0bg0IdlLdiKbCI8YZq641hphp5DOkR9Ac).

Answer (score 0):

### perl, 25

(code 24 + 1 flag -n)

```
printf"%8b",/^0x/i?hex:0
```

Answer (score 0):

## 8086 machine code - 63 bytes

Works for any input up to 125 chars (the maximum command line length in DOS)

```
00000000  be 82 00 bf 3f 01 89 fa  ad 3d 30 78 75 24 ac 3c  |....?....=0xu$.<|
00000010  0d 74 22 2c 30 3c 09 76  08 24 df 2c 07 3c 0f 77  |.t",0<.v.$.,.<.w|
00000020  11 b1 04 c1 e0 0c d0 e4  0f 92 c0 0c 30 aa e2 f6  |............0...|
00000030  eb dc ba 3d 01 b0 24 aa  b4 09 cd 21 c3 30 24     |...=..$....!.0$|
0000003f
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 24 bytes

```
q2/("0x"={seu:~Gb2bo}&;0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19opK@hZFChZFtdnFpqVeeeZJSUX6tmbfD/v0GFqYWbuYGpqamhoUVqsomBAQA)

**Explanation**

```
q      e# Read the input
2/     e# Split it into 2-length segments
(      e# Pull out the first segment
"0x"=  e# Check if it equals "0x"
{      e# If it does, run this block:
 s     e#  Join the segments back together
 eu    e#  Make the string uppercase
 :~    e#  Eval each character (A-K are 10-20)
 Gb    e#  Convert from base 16 to base 10
 2b    e#  Convert to base 2
 o     e#  Output the binary number
}&     e# (end of block)
;0     e# Delete the top stack element and push 0. If the block was run, nothing is left
       e# on the stack, so the program terminates with an error before pushing 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 107 characters

```js
f=
b=>/0x[\da-f]+$/i.test(b)&&b.match(/[\da-f](?!x)/gi).map(x=>((+('0x1'+x)).toString(2)).slice(-4)).join('')||0

console.log(f('0x1f'))
console.log(f('0x6669795966AF3000'))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 63 bytes

```
f=
x=>0|/^0x[A-Fa-f0-9]+$/.test(x)&&Number.parseInt(x).toString(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, 44 bytes

```ruby
~/^0x[0-9a-fA-F]+$/
$_=$&.hex.to_s 2rescue 0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6BUuyCpaUlaboWN3Xq9OMMKqINdC0TddMcdd1itVX0uVTibVXU9DJSK_RK8uOLFYyKUouTS1MVDCB6oFoXbDKoMDMzszS3NLU0M3N0MzYwgCoAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 92 bytes

```javascript
x=>/^0000x0*([01]+)$|/i.exec(x.replace(/./g,c=>('0x1'+c-0||1+c).toString(2).slice(1)))[1]||0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJba4MwFH7fryhsULPO5Bw1XjYs7KWve9gGg9KBS6M4pBaVkQf/u3Mus1bbsi9ghHy3HP2MvqJSFOm@Mnf5VjZx2Khwyd6hhYJbYw24WZCbmqVUKikMRQu5zyIhDUZZcifCpTEHhfOFMKGucSEIrfLnqkh3iWERWmZpS0VCyBo3dQ2NyHdlnkma5YkRd1JrTsjD7BiMzZ5eX@5nCIBwNda8rVaXNBpTGZxQ9bJJzDVEwpkqzvLbcbVl24VHosFVOgz3aUfFLe7CuOjBoxuIjoE/nHDxYw8454i@FI72G7h04S1@HrrNYelumqNf4EKa67qBF/DAdR9XNozT8NcLdfkutr8BHs76o0HWibQPQN/xnDMTmvAD7nm2b4@/41m@6fi2zfn/@aDiINoGo7@45zff)

no 2<sup>53</sup> limit

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

<s>to compare with [Shaggy's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116218/76323)</s>

```javascript
x=>(/x/i.test(x[1])*x||0).toString(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJNa4MwGL7vVwg71Ayq72u@TEcHu3jdYRsMxg7OarEUHVVGDv3vrnWZ2qhlT8AE8nwlcRd/x1VyyL/qZVFu0iZbN3r94Praz706rWpXv@MHudPHIxCvLp/rQ15s3YA0SVlU5T719uXWzdwFaAwWhNw7l/B95@n1ZeUgAMKNrXmLomsag7EMJlSdbBRzC3HCxopZPuhz2dPAC9HgKC2G87ij5gEXYBftPdoLMTHwhwmXMJPAOUcM04QZv4FLG37C@WPa9MN0MxyzgCtpQgglFVdCPEYU7DT89UJTvo3tToD9Xrc1yJpI@wQMmWQzNzTiKy4lDan9jrP8JQsp5fz/fNCZijfK@os7fvMD)

2<sup>53</sup> limit, issue when `x` end with space